# APEX Data Loader 21 Consistently Crashing - Error Message Inside

Tags: data-loader

Nearly every time that I try to use the Apex Data Loader it crashes after clicking on 'Browse' to select the file to load data from. This error message is generated. Any idea what might be causing this and/or if it is avoidable? Thanks!

#

## An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:

#

## EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x721c1fb9, pid=107360, tid=107316

#

## Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.5.0_06-b05 mixed mode)

## Problematic frame:

## C  [NetworkExplorer.dll+0x1fb9]

#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x005c8528):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=107316]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x00000008 0x721c1fb9

Registers:
EAX=0x003274ec, EBX=0x000cd7d0, ECX=0x00326e68, EDX=0x00309878
ESP=0x000cd718, EBP=0x000cd730, ESI=0x00326e68, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x721c1fb9, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000cd718)
0x000cd718:   762d5012 003274ec 762d43cc 000cd7dc
0x000cd728:   003274c8 000cd7d0 000cd754 762d5d36
0x000cd738:   003274ec 762d43cc 000cd7dc 00000000
0x000cd748:   00000001 000cd7e4 000cd7d0 000cd78c
0x000cd758:   762d558f 000cd768 762d43cc 000cd7dc
0x000cd768:   762d41e0 00000001 003274c8 00000000
0x000cd778:   762d43cc 00000000 00000000 000cd768
0x000cd788:   ca08c05b 000cd870 762d5b6b 000cd7e4

Instructions: (pc=0x721c1fb9)
0x721c1fa9:   00 00 00 c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 90 90 90 90 90
0x721c1fb9:   8b ff 55 8b ec 56 8b 75 0c 57 6a 04 59 bf 68 1e

Stack: [0x00090000,0x000d0000),  sp=0x000cd718,  free space=245k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [NetworkExplorer.dll+0x1fb9]
C  [ole32.dll+0x55d36]
C  [ole32.dll+0x5558f]
C  [ole32.dll+0x55b6b]
C  [ole32.dll+0x55a26]
C  [ole32.dll+0x55987]
C  [ole32.dll+0x55940]
C  [SHELL32.dll+0x8205b]
C  [SHELL32.dll+0x813cc]
C  [SHELL32.dll+0x8140c]
C  [SHELL32.dll+0x9cdca]
C  [SHELL32.dll+0x9fb7a]
C  [SHELL32.dll+0x8ed39]
C  [SHELL32.dll+0x8ece5]
C  [SHELL32.dll+0x8d810]
C  [explorerframe.dll+0x52e1f]
C  [explorerframe.dll+0x23ae6]
C  [explorerframe.dll+0x52db2]
C  [explorerframe.dll+0x1fce4]
C  [SHELL32.dll+0x16c494]
C  [explorerframe.dll+0x1db8b]
C  [explorerframe.dll+0x1e412]
C  [explorerframe.dll+0x1e1b8]
C  [explorerframe.dll+0x1e131]
C  [explorerframe.dll+0x117af]
C  [explorerframe.dll+0x11734]
C  [explorerframe.dll+0x3454]
C  [COMCTL32.dll+0x3463d]
C  [COMCTL32.dll+0x346e1]
C  [USER32.dll+0x16238]
C  [USER32.dll+0x168ea]
C  [USER32.dll+0x17d31]
C  [USER32.dll+0x17dfa]
C  [USER32.dll+0x32292]
C  [USER32.dll+0x32715]
C  [USER32.dll+0x3288a]
C  [USER32.dll+0x327b8]
C  [USER32.dll+0x32a59]
C  [comdlg32.dll+0x59a1]
C  [comdlg32.dll+0x16536]
C  [comdlg32.dll+0x1648c]
C  [comdlg32.dll+0x163cd]
C  [comdlg32.dll+0x432dc]
C  [comdlg32.dll+0x24518]
C  [comdlg32.dll+0x3b48f]
C  [swt-win32-3452.dll+0x6897]
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.GetOpenFileNameW(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/OPENFILENAME;)Z+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.GetOpenFileName(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/OPENFILENAME;)Z+7
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog.open()Ljava/lang/String;+890
j  org.eclipse.jface.preference.FileFieldEditor.getFile(Ljava/io/File;)Ljava/io/File;+43
j  org.eclipse.jface.preference.FileFieldEditor.changePressed()Ljava/lang/String;+26
j  org.eclipse.jface.preference.StringButtonFieldEditor$1.widgetSelected(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/SelectionEvent;)V+4
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+1003
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+71
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+25
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents()Z+84
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+59
j  org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)V+20
j  org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open()I+34
j  com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.uiActions.OperationUIAction.run()V+26
j  com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow$3.run()V+84
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run()V+11
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+29
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+5
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+74
j  org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)V+20
j  org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open()I+34
j  com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.run()V+6
j  com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI()V+59
j  com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+8
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x845a9]
V  [jvm.dll+0xd9317]
V  [jvm.dll+0x8447a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x8b44a]
C  [javaw.exe+0x14c5]
C  [javaw.exe+0x3151]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x13677]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39f42]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39f15]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.GetOpenFileNameW(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/OPENFILENAME;)Z+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.GetOpenFileName(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/OPENFILENAME;)Z+7
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog.open()Ljava/lang/String;+890
j  org.eclipse.jface.preference.FileFieldEditor.getFile(Ljava/io/File;)Ljava/io/File;+43
j  org.eclipse.jface.preference.FileFieldEditor.changePressed()Ljava/lang/String;+26
j  org.eclipse.jface.preference.StringButtonFieldEditor$1.widgetSelected(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/SelectionEvent;)V+4
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+1003
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+71
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+25
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents()Z+84
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+59
j  org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)V+20
j  org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open()I+34
j  com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.uiActions.OperationUIAction.run()V+26
j  com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow$3.run()V+84
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run()V+11
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+29
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+5
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+74
j  org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)V+20
j  org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open()I+34
j  com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.run()V+6
j  com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI()V+59
j  com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+8
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x28ef8e48 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=105868]
  0x28eb1968 JavaThread "Reference Cleaner - 2" [_thread_blocked, id=106448]
  0x28d65598 JavaThread "Reference Cleaner - 1" [_thread_blocked, id=82468]
  0x01c48048 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=106356]
  0x01c48328 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=105904]
  0x01c476c0 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=106788]
  0x01c3c390 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=89964]
  0x01c3b5c8 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=105872]
=>0x005c8528 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=107316]

Other Threads:
  0x01c37e48 VMThread [id=105112]
  0x005ce758 WatcherThread [id=106260]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 9088K, used 2801K [0x03c60000, 0x04630000, 0x063c0000)
  eden space 8128K,  22% used [0x03c60000, 0x03e2c770, 0x04450000)
  from space 960K,  99% used [0x04540000, 0x0462fff8, 0x04630000)
  to   space 960K,   0% used [0x04450000, 0x04450000, 0x04540000)
 tenured generation   total 121024K, used 2432K [0x063c0000, 0x0d9f0000, 0x23c60000)
   the space 121024K,   2% used [0x063c0000, 0x06620308, 0x06620400, 0x0d9f0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 9216K, used 9131K [0x23c60000, 0x24560000, 0x27c60000)
   the space 9216K,  99% used [0x23c60000, 0x2454ad30, 0x2454ae00, 0x24560000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x0040c000     C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Apex Data Loader 21.0_jvm\bin\javaw.exe
0x77900000 - 0x77a80000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x75850000 - 0x75960000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x75970000 - 0x759b7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x75160000 - 0x75178000     C:\Windows\system32\tsappcmp.dll
0x76110000 - 0x761bc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x76470000 - 0x76570000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x763e0000 - 0x76470000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x76220000 - 0x7622a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x75a50000 - 0x75aee000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x773e0000 - 0x77480000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76260000 - 0x76279000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x76020000 - 0x76110000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x753e0000 - 0x75440000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x753d0000 - 0x753dc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x76280000 - 0x763dc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
0x761c0000 - 0x76220000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75d10000 - 0x75ddc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x6d6e0000 - 0x6d874000     C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Apex Data Loader 21.0_jvm\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x74b80000 - 0x74bb2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x74c80000 - 0x74ccb000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d2f0000 - 0x6d2f8000     C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Apex Data Loader 21.0_jvm\bin\hpi.dll
0x778d0000 - 0x778d5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d6b0000 - 0x6d6bc000     C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Apex Data Loader 21.0_jvm\bin\verify.dll
0x6d370000 - 0x6d38d000     C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Apex Data Loader 21.0_jvm\bin\java.dll
0x6d6d0000 - 0x6d6df000     C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Apex Data Loader 21.0_jvm\bin\zip.dll
0x6d530000 - 0x6d543000     C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Apex Data Loader 21.0_jvm\bin\net.dll
0x75440000 - 0x75475000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x75960000 - 0x75966000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x72a60000 - 0x72a9c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x72d90000 - 0x72d96000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x74900000 - 0x74910000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x72aa0000 - 0x72ae4000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x73090000 - 0x73098000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x72db0000 - 0x72dc0000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x72da0000 - 0x72da5000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x74f70000 - 0x74f8c000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x75190000 - 0x75197000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x730a0000 - 0x730a6000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x72a20000 - 0x72a58000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x288d0000 - 0x28925000     C:\Users\ackermana\AppData\Local\Temp\3\swt-win32-3452.dll
0x75760000 - 0x757ef000     C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x77360000 - 0x773db000     C:\Windows\syswow64\comdlg32.dll
0x75b40000 - 0x75b97000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x74fc0000 - 0x7515e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16661_none_420fe3fa2b8113bd\COMCTL32.dll
0x76570000 - 0x771b9000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
0x75df0000 - 0x75ee5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WININET.dll
0x75bd0000 - 0x75d06000     C:\Windows\syswow64\urlmon.dll
0x75ef0000 - 0x7600e000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
0x76010000 - 0x7601c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
0x75560000 - 0x7575f000     C:\Windows\syswow64\iertutil.dll
0x74de0000 - 0x74e60000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x74370000 - 0x74383000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x73ff0000 - 0x7402c000     C:\Windows\system32\oleacc.dll
0x754d0000 - 0x75553000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x74350000 - 0x74366000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x74260000 - 0x7429b000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x72500000 - 0x72517000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x729f0000 - 0x729fb000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x72dc0000 - 0x72f2f000     C:\Windows\system32\explorerframe.dll
0x73100000 - 0x7312f000     C:\Windows\system32\DUser.dll
0x72b80000 - 0x72c32000     C:\Windows\system32\DUI70.dll
0x732e0000 - 0x733db000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x73d60000 - 0x73d91000     C:\Windows\system32\EhStorShell.dll
0x771c0000 - 0x7735d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x75b10000 - 0x75b37000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
0x75af0000 - 0x75b02000     C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
0x72690000 - 0x72785000     C:\Windows\system32\PROPSYS.dll
0x72620000 - 0x7268f000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x72f40000 - 0x72f59000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x74320000 - 0x7432b000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x72b70000 - 0x72b7a000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
0x71550000 - 0x715e4000     C:\Windows\system32\MsftEdit.dll
0x725f0000 - 0x7261a000     C:\Windows\system32\msls31.dll
0x73a50000 - 0x73a7f000     C:\Windows\system32\xmllite.dll
0x740c0000 - 0x740ce000     C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
0x731a0000 - 0x731fc000     C:\Windows\System32\StructuredQuery.dll
0x74b50000 - 0x74b58000     C:\Windows\System32\Secur32.dll
0x73d10000 - 0x73d5e000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\actxprxy.dll
0x74950000 - 0x7497b000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll
0x749e0000 - 0x749f6000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\thumbcache.dll
0x705f0000 - 0x7068f000     C:\Windows\system32\SearchFolder.dll
0x73ce0000 - 0x73d0e000     C:\Windows\system32\SHDOCVW.dll
0x70ac0000 - 0x71546000     C:\Windows\system32\ieframe.DLL
0x73080000 - 0x73089000     C:\Windows\system32\LINKINFO.dll
0x721c0000 - 0x72358000     C:\Windows\system32\NetworkExplorer.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dappdata.dir=C:\Users\ackermana\AppData\Roaming
java_command: com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QBPOSSDKRuntime;C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Migration\;C:\TAL\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.5\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
USERNAME=ackermana
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel

---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.1 Build 7600

CPU:total 4 family 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 4194303k(4194303k free), swap 4194303k(4194303k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.5.0_06-b05) for windows-x86, built on Nov 10 2005 11:12:14 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of the error message it looks like you are using Java 1.5? This is now a very old JVM version. I would recommend at least upgrading to v1.6 or v1.7 if you can. It is only [supported](http://na13.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/installing_the_data_loader.htm) on v1.6 or later.

> Java JRE 1.6 or later (Windows 7 or Windows XP)
>
> Sun JVM 1.6 or later (Windows 7 or Windows XP)

Answer (score 1):

**Not really giving an answer to your question time**

I have long given up on the normal Apex Dataloader, in my opinion it is cumbersome, hard to use, and often doesn't do what i'd expect, especially when working in another locale (Belgium in my case).

Try taking a look at [Dataloader.io](https://dataloader.io/) and/or [Jitterbit Dataloader](http://www.jitterbit.com/salesforce/data-loader) (both work cross-platform, dl.io is even cloud based)